# What is the dependancy package for Pynxc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have downloaded pynxc package from http://code.google.com/p/pynxc/ . But I did not get dependencies package list.

When I run `./pynxc --download program_name.py` ,  I get error i.e

```
No Module named wx 
No module named parser
```

For wx, I have installed wxPython. But still it is not working.

For Parser, I don't know which package I need to install. It comes while "import parser"

I am using python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) and [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) - `parser` should already be a part of your installation.

Comment: Okay.. Do you know any other packages which I need to install for pynxc except these two...

Comment: I didn't find any others when doing a `grep import *.py*` in the source code but if others are missing then python will tell you when it gets past the current problems.